# How can I sync Activate Directory users between SharePoint 2013 vs SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-online

I work on **Windows Server 2012** with **SharePoint 2013**. How can sync **AD users** from **SharePoint 2013** to **SharePoint Online**?

Comment: did you try Active Directory Synchronization or "Dir sync"? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-directory-synchronization-for-Office-365-1b3b5318-6977-42ed-b5c7-96fa74b08846

Comment: @tinamou Thanks, I have tried to follow your link and It seems to be OK. You can make an answer if you want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For syncing AD Users from your local farm to SharePoint Online you need to setup directory synchronization (DirSync).

Here is step by step guide: [Set up directory synchronization for Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-directory-synchronization-for-Office-365-1b3b5318-6977-42ed-b5c7-96fa74b08846)

Or you can use for much broader approach: [Azure AD Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect)